# USO DE ARRAYS EN CÁLCULOS DE MATRICES

Tags: python, array, numpy, datos

*El problema que estoy presentando es que cuando imprimo K me aparece dos respuesta en una misma matriz debido a los datos guardados en el array, pero; necesito que se imprima en dos matrices.

Es decir L almacena 2 y 5, al momento de imprimir K necesito que se generen dos matrices, una donde se hizo uso del 2 y la otra del 5. Estuve intentando con la opción [:] pero igualmente no funciona.

Alguien me podría indicar que comando se utiliza para aparezca secuencialmente los matrices.

Gracias!*

````
import numpy as np

ND=int(input("Ingrese el número de nodos"))
NE=int(input("Ingrese el número de elementos"))

print("COORDENADAS DE NODOS")

X=[]

for N in range(0+1,ND+1): 
   print("Coordenada",N)
   
   x=float(input("ingrese la coordenada en x"))
   X.append(x)
       
X=np.array(X)
L=np.diff(X)

I=[]
EM=[]

for EL in range (0+1,NE+1):

   print("ELEMENTO",EL)
   em=int(input("Ingrese elemento"))
   EM.append(em)
   
EM=np.array(EM)
K=[]

for MR in range (0+1,EL+1):
   print("MATRIZ RIGIDEZ ELEMENTO",EL)

   k=[[(12*E*I)/(L**3),(6)/(L**2)],
      [-(12)/(L**3),(6*)/(L**2)]] 
   
   K.append(k)
K=np.array(K)
print(K) ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que entiendo, quieres imprimir dos conjuntos de números diferentes que se encuentran en un conjunto más grande llamado "EM". Puedes hacer esto usando un ciclo que recorra los números en "EM" uno por uno, y luego buscar los números correspondientes en otro conjunto llamado "K". Aquí te muestro un ejemplo de cómo puedes hacerlo:

```
import numpy as np

ND = int(input("Ingrese el número de nodos: "))
NE = int(input("Ingrese el número de elementos: "))

print("COORDENADAS DE NODOS")

X = []

for N in range(0 + 1, ND + 1):
    print("Coordenada", N)
    x = float(input("Ingrese la coordenada en x: "))
    X.append(x)

X = np.array(X)
L = np.diff(X)

I = []
EM = []

for EL in range(0 + 1, NE + 1):
    print("ELEMENTO", EL)
    em = int(input("Ingrese elemento: "))
    EM.append(em)

EM = np.array(EM)
K = []

for MR in range(0 + 1, EL + 1):
    print("MATRIZ RIGIDEZ ELEMENTO", EL)

    k = [[(12 * E * I) / (L ** 3), (6) / (L ** 2)],
         [-(12) / (L ** 3), (6 *) / (L ** 2)]] 

    K.append(k)

K = np.array(K)

# Imprimir las matrices K correspondientes a los elementos en EM
for el in EM:
    print("Matriz K para el elemento", el)
    print(K[el - 1])
    print()  # Salto de línea para separar las matrices
```

**puede usar un "for" para recorrer uno por uno los elementos del conjunto "EM", que representa los elementos para los cuales se calculó una matriz especial llamada "matriz de rigidez K". Utilizamos el valor "-1" como índice para acceder a la matriz de rigidez correspondiente en el conjunto "K", porque en Python los índices comienzan desde 0, pero los elementos en "EM" comienzan desde 1, según el código que estás utilizando. Luego, imprimimos la matriz de rigidez correspondiente para cada elemento en "EM".**

Comment: Muchas gracias Juan.